# Where is logic to generate image from code in text2img

Tags: php, equation, tex

I am trying to implement [tex2im](http://www.nought.de/tex2im.php) , which converts the equation written  in latex format to image.

Like **\frac{1}{2} will output 1/2 in fraction**.

I downloaded the text2im file and observed the code, and to my amazement there is nothing in that file.

I mean there must be some code that takes the string like \frac{1}{2} and then checks the code \frac, takes its parameters 1 and 2 and puts it inside the image.

Similarly when the integration is done, the intrgration sign must come.

But this is the code that is there in text2im file.
**So where is the logic that analyzes the input text and creates images according to it?**

I have removed the code because that costed me -2 votes! Please remove the down votes now, I am still learning stackoverflow question rules.

Comment: where is the logic that analyzes the input text and creates images according to it?

Comment: there must be some code that checks if the function is fraction,integration,log etc... I could not find in the above code. So I asked.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Mathjax.[Mathjax download link](http://www.mathjax.org/download/)

You are trying to use tex2im which requires use of command line tool or installing the tex2im . Also the tex needs to be compiled.
But by reading the question, I think you want something that will not require installing or using command line tool and also the images are stored on your server.

The matjax dont even use images to show equations, but by using font, and so it becomes possible for google to search inside equation.